# Is there a way to make binding happen in a Silverlight control that is created in code?

Tags: silverlight-4.0, printing

I'm wanting to print a `UserControl` that binds to a view model.  I create the control in code because if I don't it prints off the edge of the page.  Apparently, there is no way to control the size or scale of a printed `UIElement` without screwing up the element that is on the Silverlight page.  So I create the 'UserControl' with the following code in the `PrintPage` event of a `PrintDocument`:

```
    private void OnPrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        PurchaseReceipt purchaseReceipt = new PurchaseReceipt();

        purchaseReceipt.DataContext = _receiptData;
        purchaseReceipt.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;

        purchaseReceipt.Margin = new Thickness(25.0);
        purchaseReceipt.Width = e.PrintableArea.Width - 50.0;

        e.PageVisual = purchaseReceipt;
    }
```

The problem is that binding doesn't work, or doesn't work in time. Is there a way to force an element to bind?